# ArrayList remove if already contains a String that starts with `it` in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String>` of data like so:

```
download
download name:string
download name:string url:string
download test:string
list
print
print name:string
reload
reload name:string
```

An example output should look like:

```
download name:string url:string
download test:string // note this one does not get filtered
list
print name:string
reload name:string
```

But I would like to remove `download` since `download name:string` exists, and also remove `download name:string` since `download name:string url:string` exists.

I tried using two arraylists and a bunch of filters but it got extremely messy and the solutions I did come up with resulted in an empty arraylist.

Example I tried:

```
                val subCommands1 = arrayListOf<String>()

                subCommands
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                    .filter {
                        var found = false
                        subCommands1
                            .stream()
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                            .reversed()
                            .forEach { comIt ->
                                if (comIt.startsWith(it)) {
                                    found = true
                                }
                            }
                        if (!found) {
                            subCommands1.add(it)
                        }
                        !found
                    }
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Any alternatives to what I'm doing would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand exactly your problem definition, but the reason why you're getting an empty list is because you're filtering the `subCommands` list with itself which means that every element will be found (found == true). When you negate the condition, then all elements are found again(found == true) but you don't filter any items (!found == false) which causes you to get the original list.

Comment: You were right, I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/4idhkQ9p) and that now gives me [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/yyxZXCvH) which isn't good either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun filterSubCommands(list: List<String>): List<String> {
    if (list.size < 2) return ArrayList(list)
    val result = ArrayList<String>()
    list.asSequence().sorted().zipWithNext().forEach { (a, b) ->
        if (!b.startsWith(a)) result.add(a)
    }
    result.add(list.last())
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this implementation by assuming that you want to keep always the longest string of parameters available:

```
fun main(): Unit {
    val filteredCommands = HashSet<String>()
    commands
        .sortedByDescending { it.length }
        .forEach { command ->
            if (filteredCommands.find { it.startsWith(command) } == null) {
                filteredCommands.add(command)
            }
        }
    println(filteredCommands.toList().joinToString())
}
```

You can run it on this [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/jTyQfTg_a).

This might not work depending on your command rules which I don't understand completely, but it works correctly for the given input.

Here's a even more functional approach, but you might find it less readable:

```
fun main(): Unit {
    val filteredCommands = commands
        .sortedByDescending { it.length }
        .fold(emptySet<String>()) { filtered, command ->
            if (filtered.find { it.startsWith(command) } == null) 
                filtered + command 
            else 
                filtered
        }
    println(filteredCommands.toList().joinToString())
}
```

Here's the [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/3bS8PZBNi) with the sample.